# I want text to be displayed when selection is made

Tags: android, text, spinner, display

So I have a spinner and what I want is when a user makes a selection a small descriptive line of text is displayed below the spinner. So lets say I have a spinner that displays superheros. You select batman and I want some text to display telling you something about Batman. How can I accomplish this.

Comment: just add a listener to the spinner..when user select batman ...display batman info

Comment: what have you attempted so far? I mean, you made any attempts to solve the problem or research any of it?

Answer (score 0):

Set a new `OnItemSelectedListener` for the Spinner:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // Code to display superhero information, for example:
        SuperHero superHero = superHeroList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // If nothing selected
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't forget to add your text into a textview that would be displayed below your spinner.

Comment: This did not work I got an error Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: setOnItemClickListener cannot be used with a spinner. I was able to get it working by using setOnItemSelectedListener

Comment: You got me pointed in the right direction so thanks and the example is correct now